# processingのgwopticsでカオス写像を描画したい

Tags: processing

カオス理論を勉強するにあたってC言語を使用して写像を描画していたのですが，gwopticsというもので簡単に描画できることを知りました

しかしプログラミングがもともと不慣れなところがあってなかなか思うようにいきません

なので今後の参考としてロジスティック写像を描画するプログラムを教えていただけないでしょうか

Comment: 最終的に描画したいグラフの画像などは挙げられますか? (分岐図なのか、二次曲線なのかなど読み取れませんでした。) また、今あるコードは載せられますか? コードを共有することで、どこで詰まっているかに沿った具体的なアドバイスをもらいやすくなります。(質問は後から[edit]できます)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます
グラフで言えば二次曲線です．情報不足で申し訳ありません
コードなのですが，まだgwopticsの勉強中でサンプルプログラムを弄って試行錯誤している段階です．
ですので，他力本願にはなってしまったのですがこちらに投稿させて頂きました．

Comment: 回答ではないのでこちらで。gwopticsは使っていませんが[Processinでロジスティック写像を詳しく見てみる ( ソフトウェア ) - まったりゲーム記 - Yahoo!ブログ](http://blogs.yahoo.co.jp/ti_tap_tgm/58951270.html)にて、ソースコード付きのものを見つけました。

Comment: ↑情報をありがとうございます．ソースコードを参考に勉強したいと思います．